# Black and white film; Journalist receives newspapers from a day into the future. One predicts his death

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, black-and-white, mystery

The film is old, maybe the 60's.

The argument is about a frustrated journalist who can not get a good article to the newspaper he works for. After a request for a "miracle", someone comes and gives him (every night) a newspaper with the news of the next day.

One day, the front page news is about his death, I think in a supermarket. In the end, and having avoided his death, he gives up tricking his luck and states that he doesn't want the newspapers any more.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspaper_from_the_future

Answer (score 6):

This is "[It Happened Tomorrow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0036962/?ref_=ttkw_kw_tt)" from 1944

> *It Happened Tomorrow, a 1944 film starring Dick Powell as a cynical newspaper reporter who gets the next day's paper from the ghost of a dead newsman and uses it to scoop rivals, bet the horses successfully, and improve his standing with his girl, until the paper predicts his own death. This film was adapted to subsequent radio performances on Academy Award Theater and Theater of Romance in 1945.*

Comment: Thanks. It´s the film, no doubt. I thought it could be newer, from 60's but i've seen it when i was 6 or 7 years old (in 1967). Thanks one more time.

Comment: @ArmandoCorreia - Don't forget to hit the "accept" button on the left hand side, next to my answer :-)